# Output summary statistics with stargazer

Tags: r

Beginner question here.  I'm trying to output the basic statistics into stargazer of a dataframe.

```
wagesub = wagepan[, c("educ", "black", "hisp", 'exper', 'expersq', 'married', 'union')] 

x = summary(wagesub)
```

I tried:

```
stargazer(x)
stargazer(x, type = "text", title = "Variable Summary", digits = 3, out = "table.txt")
```

It gives me the following error:

> Error in names(x) <- value :  'names' attribute [7] must be the same
>   length as the vector [3]

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are doing it wrong, since no input data is given I am using iris.
If you run the same command on iris , the error which you shown can be replicated as well.

**From documentation:**

The first argument(ellipsis) only accepts these things:

> ...    one or more model objects (for regression analysis tables) or
>   data frames/vectors/matrices (for summary statistics, or direct output
>   of content). They can also be included as lists (or even lists within
>   lists).

you should do it like this:

```
stargazer::stargazer(iris,summary = TRUE, out = 'tab.txt')
```

**Output**:

```
=============================================================
Statistic     N  Mean  St. Dev.  Min  Pctl(25) Pctl(75)  Max 
-------------------------------------------------------------
Sepal.Length 150 5.843  0.828   4.300  5.100    6.400   7.900
Sepal.Width  150 3.057  0.436   2.000  2.800    3.300   4.400
Petal.Length 150 3.758  1.765   1.000  1.600    5.100   6.900
Petal.Width  150 1.199  0.762   0.100  0.300    1.800   2.500
-------------------------------------------------------------
```